# Avoid nested select blocks

Tags: ruby

I have to retrieve some information related to movies and shows from a json document.

```
unique_nos = js['navigation']['category'].select{|n|  n['name']=="Home"}.first['category'].select{|s| s['name']=="#{type}"}.first['category'].select{|k| k['name']=='Movie Studios'}.first['category'].map{|l| l['categoryId']}
```

The same would go for tv shows also.

```
unique_nos = js['navigation']['category'].select{|n|  n['name']=="Home"}.first['category'].select{|s| s['name']=='TV'}.first['category'].select{|k| k['name']=='Networks'}.first['category'].map{|l| l['categoryId']}
```

I would like to avoid duplicated code performing same tasks. I would rather like to pass this block as a parameter so it could be dynamic. Is there any way to achieve this with metaprogramming?

Comment: Can you post the json fragement?

Comment: Could you not just create a method `unique_nos` that would be called `unique_nos(js, "#{type}", "Movie Studios")` in the first example and `unique_nos(js, "TV", "Networks")` in the second? (I see from @Uri's answer that we are thinking along the same lines, and also that I had forgotten the argument `js`.)

Comment: What you have is chaining, not nesting.

Comment: What is `js`? ...........

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply extract it as a method:

```
def find_unique_nos(js, type, category)
  js['navigation']['category'].select{|n| n['name']=="Home"}.first['category'].select{|s| s['name']== type }.first['category'].select{|k| k['name']==category}.first['category'].map{|l| l['categoryId']}
end
```

On a side note, `select { ... }.first` is equivalent to [`find { ... }`](http://apidock.com/ruby/Enumerable/find), so you can simplify this to:

```
def find_unique_nos(js, type, category)
  js['navigation']['category'].find{|n| n['name'] == "Home" }['category']
                              .find{|s| s['name'] == type }['category']
                              .find{|k| k['name'] == category }['category']
                              .map{|l| l['categoryId']}
end
```

If you want to be more sophisticated, you can use a builder to do the repetitive job of `find{ ... }['category']`:

```
def find_unique_nos(js, type, category)
  ['Home', type, category].inject(js['navigation']['category']) do |cat, name|
     cat.find{|n| n['name'] == name }['category']
  end.map{|l| l['categoryId']}
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Please consider to use intermediate variables to break down such long chains, it will help ease debugging and comprehension. Using your same code with reformatting:

```
def unique_numbers(json: j, type: t)
  category = type == 'TV' ? 'Networks' : 'Movie Studios'
  json['navigation']['category']
    .select{|n| n['name']=="Home"}
    .first['category']
    .select{|s| s['name'] == type }
    .first['category']
    .select{|k| k['name'] == category }
    .first['category']
    .map{|l| l['categoryId']}
end
```